# Why does `date` print date with wrong word order when localized?

Tags: locale

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I set the locale environment with the following command:

```
export LANG=ru_RU.utf8 LANGUAGE=ru_RU.utf8 LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8
```

so that `locale` now says all entries are `ru_RU.utf8`. But when I issue `date`, I get the following:

```
Чт. мая 14 12:55:36 MSK 2015
```

While it's normal to say "May 14" in English, we never say "мая 14" in Russian (it would mean "of May 14th" instead of "14th of May"). It should rather be "14 мая" or, at the worst, "май, 14".

According to `info coreutils 'date invocation'`, in `C` locale the default format string is `'+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'`, and it appears exactly what I get with `ru_RU.utf8` locale. But that same info page says that the format string depends on `LC_TIME` locale category. So, I conclude that there's a bug somewhere in system locale database.

Is it a bug indeed, or am I missing something?

Comment: in German it's `Do 14. Mai 12:36:08 CEST 2015`

Comment: @ruslan, I deleted my answer since, as you pointed out, my guess was wrong. What's worse, I had actually checked in Greek and failed to notice that the order changes there too: `LC_ALL=el_GR.utf8 date` returns `Πεμ 14 Μάι`. So yes, it does look like a bug in the Russian localization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a bug in `date`; it's caused by the definitions in `LC_TIME`. As per the `info` page:

```
Invoking date with no format argument is equivalent to invoking it
with a default format that depends on the LC_TIME locale category.
```

Now, if you open [`/usr/share/i18n/locales/ru_RU`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/ru_RU;hb=HEAD), under `LC_TIME` you will see that `date_fmt` (the date/time format) is defined as:

```
date_fmt       "<U0025><U0061><U0020><U0025><U0062><U0020><U0025><U0065>/
<U0020><U0025><U0048><U003A><U0025><U004D><U003A><U0025><U0053><U0020>/
<U0025><U005A><U0020><U0025><U0059>"
```

which translates to `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y`, that is:
`%a` - locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g. `Чт`)
`%b` - locale's abbreviated month name (e.g. `май`)
`%e` - day of month, space padded; same as `%_d` (e.g. `14`)
etc...
So, if you edit the file and swap the two conversion specifiers `%b` and `%e` (i.e. swap `<U0062>` and `<U0065>`):

```
date_fmt       "<U0025><U0061><U0020><U0025><U0065><U0020><U0025><U0062>/
<U0020><U0025><U0048><U003A><U0025><U004D><U003A><U0025><U0053><U0020>/
<U0025><U005A><U0020><U0025><U0059>"
```

and then run `locale-gen`, you will get the right date format:

```
LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8 date
Чт 14 май 13:27:14 MSK 2015
```

Last revision date (as of 2015-05-14) of the above mentioned file appears to be [2013-11-14](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=history;f=localedata/locales/ru_RU) so feel free to report a bug: `bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org`

Comment: Yes, I've explicitly supposed in the OP that it's a bug in "system locale database", not in `date`. And indeed, it works correctly after swapping these chars. Seems strange though that you get "май" while on my system it's "мая".

Comment: You can query that `date_fmt` with `locale date_fmt`. See also `locale -k LC_TIME`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, that's much easier than typing the values into hex editor to see what they represent.

Comment: @Rusian, see [that commitdiff](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=55bdd2866f23b28422d969060b3518909a12b100) for the fix on abbreviated month names and the [history of that file](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=history;f=localedata/locales/ru_RU).

Comment: Looks like the `date` and `revision` fields of that locale file have not been updated since 2000-06-29 even though there have been many  changes since. I've updated your _last revision date_ so it reflects the time it was really _revised_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - No problem, thanks for the edits and for the heads-up (`locale date_fmt`). I just went through the links you added... weird that they don't update the date/revision fields when they change locale files...

Comment: Yes, sounds like an overlook. There are even two revision dates and numbers in there (4.3 1996, 1.0 2000)...